# What is the purpose of the image_fingerprint in the Ruby gem Paperclip?

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I'm trying to track down the best fix for an error I'm getting with Paperclip. Sometimes, for reasons I don't yet know, the `image_fingerprint` field is `NULL`. The DB schema I'm using has that field with a `NOT NULL` constraint, so I end up with an `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation` 500 error.

It seems that a quick fix would simply be to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on that field, and in local development mode, it seems to work fine, but I'm nervous about allowing image records with a `NULL` value for `image_fingerprint` without knowing what that field is for.

Thoughts?

Comment: See https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#checksum--fingerprint – there's a rake task to refresh the fingerprints.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! So it's an MD5 checksum... but will there be any problems if it's NULL? That's what I don't understand

Comment: I'm not sure what the fingerprint / checksum is supposed to do. But I'd say you shouldn't have NULL values in the first place.

Comment: Yeah. I opted to just validate it's presence. If it's not there, the image is "invalid" and the user has to try again. It solves the immediate problem, but I still don't know why thoughtbot included the fingerprint.